# client.application.commands.set not work discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to deploy slash commandes with my Discord bot.
But I get this error :

```
client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands)
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'commands')
```

My handler :

```
["loadEvents", "loadSlashsCommand"].forEach((handler) => {
    require(`./handler/${handler}`)(client);
});

//Config.json valid ? requirements
const { checkValid } = require('./Functions/Validation/checkValid')

//Check if valid
checkValid()

//Login
console.log((`${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()} -`), chalk.bgBlue('Connexion à l\'API Discord en cours...'))
client.login(BotToken)
```

My loadSlashsCommands :

```js
const chalk = require("chalk");
const { glob } = require("glob");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const globPromise = promisify(glob);
const config = require('../Configuration/config.json')

module.exports = async (client) => {
  const fs = require("fs");
  const slashCommands = await globPromise(
    `${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`
  );
  const arrayOfSlashCommands = [];
  slashCommands.map((value) => {
    const file = require(value);
    if (!file?.name) return;
    client.slashCommands.set(file.name, file);
    arrayOfSlashCommands.push(file);

  });
  await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands)
};
```

I don't know why the error occurs. I'm using discordjs v14

Comment: Make sure `client` is defined properly. The error means that the property `application` doesn't exist on your `client` object, which is probably the issue.

Comment: Client.application is null until the websocket connection is ready. Maybe try loading slash commands in the event handler for `ready`?

Answer (score 0):

The `await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands)` must be in `ready` event.

So what you can do is add a `ready` event listener

See below

```js
const chalk = require("chalk");
const { glob } = require("glob");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const globPromise = promisify(glob);
const config = require('../Configuration/config.json')

module.exports = async (client) => {
  const arrayOfSlashCommands = [];
  const fs = require("fs");
  const slashCommands = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`);

  slashCommands.map((value) => {
    const file = require(value);
    if (!file?.name) return;

    client.slashCommands.set(file.name, file);
    arrayOfSlashCommands.push(file);
  });

  client.on('ready', () => {
    await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands)
  });
};
```